# Docker error: Service 'app' failed to build

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new to docker, currently following book to learn Django.

1. Is it necessary to be in virtual environment when running the below
   command?
2. I have gone through docker basic videos which says it saves each apps as images. But where these images are saved?.
3. Does this line make the current pc root directory or dockers Image '
   WORKDIR /usr/src/app'

ADD is placed before RUN in the Dockerfile.

**$ sudo docker-compose build**

But I got these errors.

```
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder912263941/config/requirements.txt: no such file or directory
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    mysql-client default-libmysqlclient-dev

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ADD config/requirements.txt ./
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip; \
  pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN django-admin startproject myproject .;\
  mv ./myproject ./origproject
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: 'mysql:5.7'
  app:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - './project:/usr/src/app/myproject'
      - './media:/usr/src/app/media'
      - './static:/usr/src/app/static'
      - './templates:/usr/src/app/templates'
      - './apps/external:/usr/src/app/external'
      - './apps/myapp1:/usr/src/app/myapp1'
      - './apps/myapp2:/usr/src/app/myapp2'
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    links:
      - db
```

**requirements.txt**

```
Pillow~=5.2.0
mysqlclient~=1.3.0
Django~=2.1.0
```

Comment: It could be that the `config/requirements.txt` file is under one of the folders like `myproject` or `myapp1`. The `config` folder needs to be in the same place as your `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it necessary to be in virtual environment when running the below
>   command?

No, the docker build environment is isolated from the host. Any virtualenv on the host is ignored on the build context and the resulting image.

> I have gone through docker basic videos which says it saves each apps
>   as images. But where these images are saved?.

The images are stored somewhere in `/var/lib/docker` but isn't meant to be browsed manually. You can send the images somewhere with `docker push <image:tag>` or save them with `docker save <image:tag> -o <image>.tar`

> Does this line make the current pc root directory or dockers Image ' WORKDIR > /usr/src/app'

That line change the current workdir on the image.

```
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder912263941/config/requirements.txt: no such file or directory
```

This error means that you do not have `config/requirements.txt` in your current directory where build is run. Adjust your path on the Dockerfile properly.

Comment: thanks, but its specified in book to place the requirements.txt inside config sub-directory.  The config directory is only present in myproject/myproject/config.  There also exist myproject/myproject/tmp where settings.py,urls.py and wsgi.py is placed.These directory's are not created by Django. When to use these directory? Is this some standard?

Comment: @VAsplash i don't mean to move the requirements.txt file but use the correct path on the dockerfile. Maybe did you mean  myproject/config/requirements.txt? is not clear in your question the location of the requirements.txt file in relation of the docker-compose.yml

Comment: The default settings.py file location is changed. It moved to new tmp directory which is created in default settings.py location. But at the same level of tmp directory  where config directory is created. Since the requirements.txt is previously placed inside config as specified in the book. Why the author using those directory. Is this some standard?

Answer (score -7):

```
$ docker-compose up -d
```

This will download the necessary Docker images and create a container for the web service.